# Trying to create a controlled switcher button

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I've picked up this code online (it's high up in the google results) :
https://codepen.io/BuiltByEdgar/pen/jWOVYQ

but I've grown annoyed with it's code.

I'm trying to have a duo of these buttons where default state is on and having both off is not allowed. The UI behavior I've chosen for that is to simply re-enable the other if it's sibling is being turned off :

```
onONEClick() {
    let {
        TWO,
        ONE,
    } = this.state;

    if (TWO) {
        ONE = !ONE;
    } else if (ONE) {
        TWO = !TWO;
        ONE = !TWO;
    } else {
        ONE = !ONE;
    }

    this.setState({
        ONE,
        TWO,
    });
    this.props.callBack({
        ONE,
        TWO,
    });
}
onTWOClick() {
    let {
        TWO,
        ONE,
    } = this.state;

    if (ONE) {
        TWO = !TWO;
    } else if (TWO) {
        TWO = !TWO;
        ONE = !ONE;
    } else {
        TWO = !TWO;
    }

    this.setState({
        ONE,
        TWO,
    });
    this.props.callBack({
        ONE,
        TWO,
    });
}
```

and the render:

```
     <div>
        <div className="switch-container">
            <label>
                <input
                    onChange={this.onONEClick}
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="switch"
                    value={this.state.ONE}
                    checked={this.state.ONE}
                />
                <div>
                    <span><g className="icon icon-toolbar grid-view" /></span>
                    <span><g className="icon icon-toolbar ticket-view" /></span>
                    <div />
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        ONE
    </div>
    <div>
        <div className="switch-container">
            <label>
                <input
                    onChange={this.onTWOClick}
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="switch"
                    value={this.state.TWO}
                    checked={this.state.TWO}
                />
                <div>
                    <span><g className="icon icon-toolbar grid-view" /></span>
                    <span><g className="icon icon-toolbar ticket-view" /></span>
                    <div />
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
        TWO
    </div>
```

simple enough right?

problem is react hates that my switcher is an input of type "checkbox" :
[image: error message]

and as you can see I've done my best to avoid this happening but I think it simply isn't in the cards to have an input type and change it's checked state other than by a human.

So I'm thinking maybe I can solve the issue by reconstructing the checkbox with just divs. (the label tag is also in violation of ESLint)

ANSWERED BY JLAITIO :

and here's what I added (top part of the file with props declaration and constructor) :

```
const propTypes = {
    value: React.PropTypes.object,
    type: React.PropTypes.string,
    callBack: React.PropTypes.func,
    ONE: React.PropTypes.bool,
    TWO: React.PropTypes.bool,
};

const defaultProps = {
    callBack: () => {},
    onChange: () => {
    },
    value: { type: '' },
    ONE: true,
    TWO: true,
};



class ProviderInfosComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const initialValue = props.value;
        this.state = {
            ...initialValue,
            ONE: this.props.ONE,
            TWO: this.props.TWO,
        };
        this.onONEClick = this.onONEClick.bind(this);
        this.onTWOClick = this.onTWOClick.bind(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error, if at *any* point your `value` attribute is not set, or set to a value that is `undefined`, and then subsequently it is an existing React state value.

My best guess would be that your constructor does not initialize `ONE` and `TWO`, hence the value being `undefined` to start with. Then when you actually have a value, the component transfers from being an uncontrolled (="component state independent of React") to controlled(="component state tied directly to React state").

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @jlaitio's answer,

You don't have to set a value for a checkbox input. You can just use checked prop of the component. Also a small improvement for your changed functions might be useful to follow up the values easier.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ONE: true,
      TWO: true
    };
  }
  onONEChange = (event) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      ONE: event.target.checked,
      TWO: (event.target.checked === false ? true : prevState.TWO) // change state of TWO if ONE is false else just leave it as is
    }, () => {
        this.props.callBack({ ONE: this.state.ONE, TWO: this.state.TWO });
    });
  }
  onTWOChange = (event) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      ONE: (event.target.checked === false ? true : prevState.ONE), // change state of ONE if TWO is false else just leave it as is
      TWO: event.target.checked
    }, () => {
        this.props.callBack({ ONE: this.state.ONE, TWO: this.state.TWO });
    });
  }
```

Comment: actually I do : for context this is a child of a child of a child component which is grouping all of the states of these into a single maintain-state redux object. I don't know how I'd pick up it's state if I was using the checked property, is that possible? if yes I'd like to know how

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you are doing completely but from what I understood you can set ref props for inputs and read checked instead of value. `ref={(ref) => { this.inputOneRef = ref; }}` `this.inputOneRef.checked`